# "something just not come easy" -- correct grammatical structure with implied meaning

Tags: sentence-structure

Would it be right to say

> Fame and glory just not come easy.

meaning "someone should work hard to become famous"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. When English verbs are expressed in a negative sense, you have to use a form of the word *do* with it:

> Fame and glory just do not come easy.

2. *Easy* is an adjective - and adjectives modify nouns.  Words ending in *-ly* are adverbs - adverbs modify verbs.  So, you want to use *easily* instead of *easy*.  Though in real speech you will not hear this rule followed consistently, especially with *easy* and a few other common words.

> Fame and glory just do not come easily.

Comment: "Easy" can be used as a flat adverb (A flat adverb being an adverb formed from an adjective without adding _-ly_). Though, admittedly, this usage may be more informal.

Answer (score 3):

Negative sentences using *not* require an auxiliary verb in English. The word *not* belongs with the auxiliary. In the Original Poster's example, they use the present simple. In positive sentences the present simple doesn't use an auxiliary. If we want to make the sentence negative we need to use the auxiliary *DO*. So for the Original Poster's sentence this gives us:

> Fame and glory just don't come easy.

Because this use of *easy* instead of *easily* is quite informal we would definitely want to contract the *did* and *not* here.

Comment: Can we limit that to contemporary English?  "Fame and glory come not just easily" might be stuffy, old-fashioned and very much worth avoiding, but it is still English.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan I find that ungrammatical on its own, but ok if there's a following phrase, so *not just easily, but ...*. Notice that that does not negate the sentence as a whole, because it will still take a negative tag. Nice point though. Will ponder ...